# a function that is in $L^2$

Tags: lp-spaces

Can anyone give me an example of $f(x) $ such that $ f \in L^2 ( \mathbb R)$ but $  x^{\frac{1}{2}} f \notin L^1 ( \mathbb R ) $. Thanks!

---

It seems that $f(x) = x^\alpha$ doesn't work...

Comment: I thought $f \notin {L_1}$. I gave my answer based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(x)=x^{-1}\chi_{[1,\infty]}$

Comment: I think you need to add a $\log$ there, i.e. $f(x) = \log(x)x^{-1/2}\chi_{[1,\infty)}$. Unless I'm doing something stupid, your function is not in $L^2$ since $\int_1^\infty x^{-1} dx = \infty$.

Comment: @snarski: you are right. I actually meant $x^{-1}\chi_{[1,\infty]}$. Then the result of multiplying $x^{1/2}$ gives my function. Let me edit the answer.